# Live Image resized and mover (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I need a plugin or a sample code because I've a div with a background and the user once has uploaded his own image he must be able to live resize it and move above the background provided by me.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about this one: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/, or this one is maybe better http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! This is useful for crop, what I need is live move and resize an directly an image.